# Elasticsearch - adding a separate query for aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

Below is the elasticsearch query I am using to get the results and the filter options for the results from the aggregation. The problem is that whenever someone applies a filter, the overall result changes and hence the filter options also changes. I do not want the filter options to changes unless query parameter change. For now I am making two calls:

1. get all results without aggregation
2. Get all filters by using aggregation and setting the size parameter to 0

This approach uses 2 api requests and hence doubling the time. Can this be done in one request only ?

**First call: All results without aggregation**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": {
              "query": "cooking",
              "boost": 2,
              "slop": 10
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "cooking",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "filter": [
        {
          "match": {
            "is_paid": false
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "sort": [],
  "from": 0,
  "size": 15
}
```

**Second call: getting filters**

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "title": {
              "query": "cooking",
              "boost": 2,
              "slop": 10
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "title": {
              "query": "cooking",
              "boost": 1
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "courseCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "provider",
        "size": 100
      }
    },
    "paidCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "is_paid",
        "size": 3
      }
    },
    "subjectCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "subject",
        "size": 30
      }
    },
    "levelCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "level",
        "size": 4
      }
    },
    "pacingCount": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "pacing_type",
        "size": 4
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: if you don't care about the filter in 2nd query, you can put `size` as non-zero which gives you the `hits` similar to 1st query

Comment: in that case I won't be able to filter queries. If I add filters, aggregation will affect too.

Comment: You can add the filter in aggregations

Comment: I need filters in main queries or else users will not be able to filter through thousands of records. Adding filters again in aggregation query will filter the filtered results. If i keep filters in only aggregation query then again, user wont be able to filter the results.

Comment: adding global aggregation also didn't help as it included all the docs.